# why .format crashes an app only on device?

Tags: android, kotlin

while testing the app that I'm working on right now I stepped into weird problem, my app works fine on emulator but crashes on my device(huawei p9, I don't know if it really matters). It seems like this two particular lines of code are reason of crash(app works fine on device after removing this formatting code):

```
val formatedBruttoPrice = "%.2f".format(price).toDouble()         // price is a double
val formated            = "%.2f".format(totalPrice).toDouble()    // totalPrice is also a double
```

The error that I get   `java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "2,0"`

Any ideas why? And how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is due to differences in locales.
The emulator converts `2.0` to `"2.0"` due to english locales, but your device uses something else which produces `"2,0"`.
Then you are calling `.toDouble()` so it tries to parse.
So you went from double to string to double. Just remove the `.toDouble()` calls and use the strings instead.